# Why document selector doesn't work for mouseenter event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$.fn.right = function() {
   return $(document).width() - (this.offset().left + this.outerWidth());
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
          top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
          right = self.right();
      $('body').append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about "+tag_name+"</div>");
      
      $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", right: right + "px"}).fadeIn(200);  
      
    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    if(this.iid){
      clearTimeout(this.iid)
      $('.tag_info').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
    body{
      padding: 20px;
      direction: rtl;
    }

    a {
        color: #3e6d8e !important;
        background-color: #E1ECF4;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    .tag_info{
      position: absolute;
      width: 130px;
      height: 100px;
      display:none;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a>long-length-tag</a>
    <a>tag</a>
```

It works fine. But in reality, the content *(those tags)* will be created later. I mean they will be created as an ajax response. So `$('a')` doesn't select them.

Now I'v written it like `$(document).bind('mouseenter', 'a', function(){ ... })` to make that working even for the DOM which is created after page loading.

But as you see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhxyn9sg/), it doesn't work. Does anybody know what's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the event with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This works for future elements as well.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'a', function(){ ... });
```

And, as @Gregg has answered, `.bind()` has been replaced by `.on()`. That's the actual cause why your fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: That's not an issue here. It's more of an alternative

Comment: @Mr.Alien -- The linked fiddle doesn't work with `.bind()`, but works with `.on()`.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Do you know what's the problem? I've tested both `on()` and `bind()`, but neither work

Comment: What you mean it works with `.on()`?  Are you saying that popup will be hide when your mouse leaves the tag in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhxyn9sg/1/)?

Comment: @stack -- Yes it should've worked if you've written `.on('mouseleave', 'a', function(){`. You forgot specifying the target tag `a` in the `on` event binding. :)

Answer (score 2):

The [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function has replaced `bind()` since jQuery 1.7. If you read the documentation, you'll note that `live()` was actually used for delegate events like what you're trying to achieve while the `bind()` method was not; binding events to elements that will be added to the DOM later. The `on()` function can do this. Either from the document itself or from a direct descendent.

Comment: So you mean I have to use `on()` instead of `bind()` ?

Comment: You're fiddle isn't adding anything to the DOM after the initial load. I see the hover effect. So I'm not sure how you'd assume it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

When anchor tag are being created in response of your AJAX call, put id in it like this:

```
$('body').append("<div class='tag_info' id='myTag'>Some explanations about "+tag_name+"</div>");
```

and then you can bind event mouseenter or mouseleave like this:

```
 $('#myTag').bind('mouseenter',  function(){
    alert('Mouse Enter in your Anchor Tag');
 }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    alert('Mouse leave');
});
```